# How to make a simple "Approve or reject" system

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am making an web application for an iOS app I made. I want to administrate the questions in the application that I have made, but now I also want users to have the oppertunity to submit questions to the web application. However, the questions from the users can't just be added to the list becaus I want to approve that it is a valid question first.

I thought of making the following:

- A page where the users can register and submit a question.
- This is handled by a seperate backing bean (not the same as I use in the admin panel)
- The question is so passed to the EJB which again persist the question.
- Then I have a list of user submitted questions and I have the option to "Approve", meaning that I will have the oppertunity to persist the question in the approved question table.

With this approach I must make a duplicate of the question table (as well as the answer and category table) and have a prefix or something (user_submitted_questions for example)

Is this a "good" way of doing it? Or can I do it better/more effcient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't duplicate the entire question. Instead, try adding a `status` field to the Question object. When questions come into the web application, they can be persisted with a SUBMITTED status. Once you review them, they can be updated to be either APPROVED or REJECTED. You can code your front-end to only show questions with `status == APPROVED` on the public view.

This avoids the overhead of maintaining 2 question tables/objects (as you evolve the system, now you'll only need to maintain 1 table/object as you add/remove fields). The performance of approving a question should improve as well since it is just updating a single field rather than inserting a whole new row. If your table grows too quickly, you can always build an archive (or truncate) job that purges or moves rejected questions.

Comment: +1.  Very similar to our approach, and using the status field allows more options than just "yes" "no" and null.

Comment: So I just add a column to the Question table (and update the entity) named for example status of type..VARCHAR? And then I have the oppertunity to set different statuses. Or should I be using another datatype and have I understood it correct? Thank you=)

Comment: Yes, I'd add a column to Question, but I would make it a string (VARCHAR) so I can capture multiple states. Right now you have 3: Submitted, Approved, Rejected. It's conceivable that you'd have more later so using a string reduces the need for refactoring. In the object, you can use an Enum to ensure no invalid values get persisted into the status column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're saving the questions and answers in a database...

We did it in our system by simply having a nullable bit column in our database named "Approved" and a corresponding timestamp.  When the question comes in, the value is initially null.

At the time it is approved or rejected, we set the bit flag appropriately, and update the timestamp to show when it was approved or rejected.  It's a lot simpler than duplicate tables.